# Pandas Dataframe Autofill

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm newbie with Python and I'm trying to do the following:

1. I have a single column dataframe with tweets (each row contains a tweet string)
2. I can split the words of any tweet using `df[row].split()`

However, I cannot find how to create a `pd.DataFrame` where:

1. its rows will be words
2. its columns will be the tweets

---

I tried to fill my dataframe like I did in my early R scripts, but it doesn't work i.e.

```
for x in range(0, len(tweets)):
    words[,x] = pd.DataFrame(data=tweets[x].split())
```

I found out that `[,]` do not operate like R in dataframes, but I cannot even find how I can fill my `DataFrame` without specifying the columns as an array instead of defining the total column number. So far, I have only succeeded to create a list of words.

---

So, my questions are the following:

1. How can I create a the `words` DataFrame in this case?
2. How can I create a `n*m` dataframe by specifying only the row/column length instead of using an array?
3. Is there any way to extract more than 1 row by time using `df[row].split()`?

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't the best solution, but it does what you're looking for:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [
    ['This is a sentence.'],
    ['This is also a sentence.'],
    ['Hi.']
]

data = pd.DataFrame(data)

max_len = 0
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    length = len(row.values[0].split())
    if length > max_len:
        max_len = length
words = pd.DataFrame(index=range(data.shape[0]), columns=range(max_len))
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    j = 0
    for word in data.iloc[i].values[0].split():
        words.iloc[i, j] = word
        j += 1

print(words)
```

output:

```
      0    1     2          3          4
0  This   is     a  sentence.        NaN
1  This   is  also          a  sentence.
2    Hi  NaN   NaN        NaN        NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found another - similar to the proposed - way to do it:

```
tweets = pd.DataFrame(data.tweet)

max_words = 0
for i in range(0, len(tweets)):
    if max_words < len(tweets.iloc[i,0].split()):
        max_words = len(tweets.iloc[i,0].split())

words = pd.DataFrame(columns= range(len(tweets)), index= range(max_words))

for i in range(0, max_words):
    words.iloc[i] = tweets.tweet.str.split().str[i]
```